# Does jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js css include the customed all file under development-bundle?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, normalize

Folks , 
Thank all of you in advance ,  and Here I want to ask two questions :

Question 1: 
I try to use the JQuery and JQueryUI to building my website , and I have custom downloaded the JQuery UI , and unzip it , I found that it contains development-bundle, There are lots of xxx-css and js ,  I guess that I only need to copy the \jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom\js and \jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom\css to my Web project , and the jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom\development-bundle are contained by them and I needn't to copy their css and JS, Right ?

Question 2: 
How doesn't my page design to both support the normalize.css and JQuery UI ? I think there are some conflict, Right ?

Comment: For question1 , I means that the development-bundle is just for demo and support the help for us to develop , Right ?

Comment: For question2 , I means How to both support the all normalize and Jquery features without conflict .

Comment: Actually , I really doubt my expression towards my these two questions . Hope some of you can understand what I asked , That will be a luck to me .